# combobox IsFocused problems wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, triggers

I've created wpf ComboBox template. And I've added trigger on IsFocused property, to change my ComboBox Border color. But for some reasons it's working only when It's focused with Tab button. It doesn't change border color when I made selection in Combobox. How to solve this problem? Here is template code:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF1388B7" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="#c1bebe" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Color="#fffae5" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Path Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FF436B13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" x:Name="Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Chrome" Value="2,2,2,0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="Chrome" Value="3,3,2,2"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Chrome" Value="#FF1388B7"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="#fef2be"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FF1388B7" TargetName="Chrome"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#83bff6" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" MappingMode="Absolute" EndPoint="0,20" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>

</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RoundCorners="false">
                    <Path Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" x:Name="Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"/>
                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FF1388B7" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        </Popup>
        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"/>
        <TextBox Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="true"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FF1388B7" TargetName="Border"/>
        </Trigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup Margin="1" x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="#f6fafe" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}" BorderBrush="#FF1388B7" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="90"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FF1388B7"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"   Margin="2,2,2,2">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Might be something else in your code, the above style work ok.

Comment: Try to add items into ComboBox and select one of them, then remove cursor from ComboBox and tell me if border is not LightGray

Comment: After you pick an item the border changes back to gray.

Comment: Yes, but it's focused at that moment, so it should be Blue

Comment: Check if your button IsFocusable = true, try focusing it explicitely by calling button.Focus() and see if it'll make difference.

Comment: <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
It's focusing when I press Tab button. And it's still focused after item selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be with WPF's [DependencyProperty Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) rules

The color specified in `ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton` Style:

```
<Border x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="#c1bebe"
        BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
```

is taking precendence over the triggered color defined in your ComboBox's ControlTemplate.Triggers

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FF1388B7"/>
</Trigger>
```

Change it to `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}` and it will work correctly

```
<Border x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
```

Comment: Not helped:( I have changed all IsFocused properties to IsKeyboardFocusWithin, result is the same. Try it please with my template, maybe you will find the reason

Comment: @TimurMustafaev I changed my answer. Realized it was a problem with the style itself, and not the trigger.